# How can i deploy to an Azure App service using msbuild without building project?

Tags: msbuild

I want to deploy to Azure app service. I want to follow the following steps

1. msbuild to build the solution for release
2. msbuild to deploy the project file

I use the following in Powershell

```
$projectpath = "c:\repo\myproject.csproj"
& MSBuild.exe" $projectpath `
/p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 `
/p:Configuration=Release `
/p:Platform="AnyCPU" `
/p:DeployOnBuild=true `
/p:PublishProfile=$DeploymentXmlFilePath `
/p:Password=$password
```

How can i do just a deploy not  /p:DeployOnBuild=true ` and force the deployment because I have already built the project in release mode.I assume i wont need /p:Configuration=Release  either.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The `/p` argument passes a set of properties and values to MSBuild. Properties are not actions or commands. They are values that will be used as flags and/or data.

Visual Studio generated C# projects support a standard set of targets: `build`, `clean`, `rebuild`, and `publish`.

The default target is `build`.

Your command line, because it is not otherwise specifying a target, is running the `build` target. Because the `DeployOnBuild` property is set to `true`, a deployment is performed as part of the `build`.

To deploy only, run the `publish` target. The `/t` argument is used to specify the set of targets to run.

e.g.

```
$projectpath = "c:\repo\myproject.csproj"
& MSBuild.exe" $projectpath `
/t:Publish `
/p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 `
/p:Configuration=Release `
/p:Platform="AnyCPU" `
/p:DeployOnBuild=true `
/p:PublishProfile=$DeploymentXmlFilePath `
/p:Password=$password
```